# a question about Lp norm of curvature on convex curves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose we have two strictly convex closed curves $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$, $C_{1}$ contains $C_{2}$, 
then can we conclude $\int_{C_{1}} \kappa_{1}^{p} ds\geq \int_{C_{2}} \kappa_{2}^{p} ds$, $\kappa_{1}$ and $\kappa_{2}$ are corresponding curvatures of $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$, 
$p$ is between 0 and 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $C_2$ be the unit circle and $C_1$ be a big square with corners rounded off by circle arcs of radius $r\ll 1$. The integral for $C_2$ is the same as for the $r$-circle and this is very small.

Comment: Actually, small circles have large curvature so it is not so straight forward. For example for $p=1$ the integrals are equal (to $2\pi$). For $p = 0$ one compares arc-lengths and so we also have the inequality. 

Comment: @alvarezpaiva, the inequality holds only for $p=0$ or $1$;
and Sergei's example shows that it does not hold for any  $p\in(0,1)$. 

Comment: That's right. I mixed up the scaling factor (of 1-p).

Comment: I think alvarezpaiya's 1st comments make sense. for Sergei's example, when p=0 the inequality in my question obviously right, and in fact it is a strict inequality. Then notice that the curves are strictly convex, so at least for when p very colose to 0, for sergei's example, the inequality still holds. 

Comment: Of course I assumed that $p$ is strictly between 0 and 1. The strict convexity is irrelevant because one can approximate.


Comment: @rrrq: my first comment only made sense in that Sergei understood "between" as "strictly between" and I didn't. It is usually not so easy to construct natural functionals of the space of convex curves (or convex bodies) that are monotonous with respect to inclusion. Your functionals are also invariant under Euclidean motions. It may be that
arc-length and Euler characteristic (cases $p = 0$ or $1$) are the only two such functionals, at least under reasonable hypotheses.